# SQL connection dies after one call

Tags: php, mysql

I have a custom class that takes a sql connection as a parameter. I use that to populate the class, and then I'm trying to use it again to modify the results on screen. But after the first use, I can't use it anymore.

connection.php:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'loveConnections');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

personalityProfile.php (front end)

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['interests'])) {
    $interests = new Interests($conn, $_SESSION['id']);
    $_SESSION['interests'] = $interests;
} else {
    $interests = $_SESSION['interests'];
}
```

interestsObject.php

```
class Interests {

  // properties
  public $conn;
  public $id;
  public $interestsArray = [];

  public function __construct($conn, $memberId = null, $intArray = [
    'basketball' => false,
    'bowling' => false,
    'movies' => false,
  ]) {
    $this->conn = $conn;
    $this->id = $memberId;
    $this->interestsArray = $intArray;
    $this->popArraySql();
  }

  public function popArraySql() {
    $memInterests = [];
    $sql = "SELECT i.interest
              FROM memberInfo m
              Join MemberInterestLink mi on (mi.memberID_FK = m.memberID_PK)
              Join interests i on (mi.interestID_FK = i.interestID_PK)
              WHERE memberID_PK = $this->id";
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
```

`$this->conn` works perfectly here

```
    foreach ($result as $row) {
      array_push($memInterests, $row['interest']);
    }

    foreach ($this->interestsArray as $key => $value) {
      for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($memInterests); $i++) {
        if ($memInterests[$i] === $key) {
          $this->interestsArray[$key] = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public function insertUpdateQuery() {
    var_dump($this->conn);
    foreach ($this->interestsArray as $key => $val) {
      echo $key . "<br>";
      $select = "SELECT interestID_PK from interests where interest = '" . $key . "'";
      echo $select;
      $result = $this->conn->query($select);
```

when I try and use it later though, I get a `Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli`. Additionally, if I try and var_dump it, I get `Warning: var_dump(): Property access is not allowed yet`

```
      var_dump($result);
      if ($val === true) {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO MemberInterestLink (memberID_FK, interestID_FK) VALUES ($this->id, $interestKey)";
        $this->conn->query($insert);
      } else {
        $delete = "DELETE FROM MemberInterestLink WHERE interestID_FK = $interestKey";
        $this->conn->query($delete);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I never close the connection, which is what most of the related answers suggested the cause may be. It's like my $conn variable just stops working after the first use.

Comment: the object goes away when the class expires!

Comment: When does the class expire? I didn't think it ever went away.

Comment: use destructor method to log. Let me know whether the object dies before you access the connection property.

Comment: so I just added a basic destructor method like this: `function __destruct() {
    echo "Destroying \n";
  }`

and it showed up the first time I opened the relevant page

Comment: I just decided to do it the old fashioned way and have `$conn` be passed into the method instead of being an attribute that gets called.

Comment: yes this is why you can't access the connection object. So not everything you want will be possible in programming :)